# Specifying path for an hbm.xml file from a different project in another project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In my `Java Spring MVC` Web application, I have a common project say `Project A` and another project say `Project B`. `Project A` only contains the common classes shared across various project and one `hbm.xml`-file I use and is added as dependency for all the sub projects. I have a common method to save some data to the database. I use `hibernate` for my database operations. I have created the `hbm.xml` file in `Project A` so that it can be used by all sub projects. In the `root-context.xml` file of my `Project B` I have the following:

```
   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>              
                <value>/hibernatemappings/support/SupportItem.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>/hibernatemappings/support/SupportPriority.hbm.xml</value>               
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I want to add the `hbm.xml`-file from my Project A to this file, but I am getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException:`. The base project (Project A) only has Java classes, one `hbm.xml`-file and do not have a `web.xml` or `root-context.xml` file.

Comment: If `Project A` is the base-project and you created the `.hbm.xml` in the base-project..... how can the base-project only have java classes?

Comment: Its a project with only the common java classes that are shared across all projects. Its not the main project, its a common project

Comment: You did not answer, either in Project-A are **only** classes inside OR there are classes **and** the `hbm.xml`-files inside!!!

Comment: classes and only one hbm.xml file

Comment: Please look inside the `projectA.jar` now and please tell the path of the `hbm.xml` inside the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is at location "Project B/src/main/resources/hibernatemappings/audit/Audit.hbm.xml"

You can get the absolute path of that file as below

> this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hibernatemappings/audit/Audit.hbm.xml").getPath()